# Which insect is this?

Tags: species-identification

I just found what i think is an insect on floor of my balcony. From what i know, it is a Praying mantis. I want to keep it as a pet but for that i want to its exact species.

[image: Image_1 of insect]

[image: Image_2 of insect]

[image: Image_3 of insect]

---

If it helps:
 Location: Bangalore, India
Temperature : $23^{\circ}$ C

---

Could someone help me identify it pleas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume it is an Indian bark Mantis , *Humbertiella ceylonica*.

[image: Image2]

> This mantis can be kept at between 21 and 28 degrees comfortably and does not need a drop in temperature at night.

References: [bugzuk.com](http://www.bugzuk.com/insects/praying-mantis/humbertiella-ceylonica) and [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Humbertiella%20ceylonica&biw=1366&bih=635&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-yZDQz5vPAhVGbT4KHeaKDKUQ_AUICCgD#imgrc=hgVOEOCocjNbjM%3A)